# my component doesn't get rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Altough I load every file I does not show any angularjs component. 
I kinda lost because It's not returning any error or anything.
I'm really stuck. 
[webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjDyw.png)

[treeview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Iqf.png)

**root.module.js**

```
 import {suggestions} from './suggestions/suggestions.module';
import {commons} from './commons/commons.module';
import {rootComponent} from './root.component';
import {templates} from './root.templates';
import {i18n} from './root.vendors.module';

export const root =
  angular.module('root', [
    templates,
    commons,
    suggestions

    //vendors
  ])
  .component('rootComponent', rootComponent);
```

**suggestions.module.js**

```
import {suggestionsComponent} from './suggestions.component';
import {suggestionComponent} from './suggestion/suggestion.component';
import {suggestionActionComponent} from './suggestion/suggestion-action/suggestion-action.component';
import {suggestionViewerComponent} from './suggestion/suggestion-viewer/suggestion-viewer.component';

export const suggestions =
  angular.module('suggestions', [])
    .component('suggestions', suggestionsComponent)
    .component('suggestionComponent', suggestionComponent)
    .component('suggestionActionComponent', suggestionActionComponent)
    .component('suggestionViewerComponent', suggestionViewerComponent)
    .name;
```

**suggestions.component.js**

```
export const suggestionsComponent = {
  bindings: {},
  templateUrl: 'suggestions/suggestions.html'
};
```

**suggestions.pug**

```
h1 soy suggestions
  suggestion
```

**root.pug**

```
h2 hi from root
suggestions
```

**root.html(pug rendered)**

```
<h2>hi from root!</h2><suggestions></suggestions>
```

**root.component.js**

```
export const rootComponent = {
  templateUrl: 'root.html'
};
```

The only thing that gets rendered is the h1 but not the component.

Comment: well I used pug in other proyect and returns  <suggestions></suggestions> let me post the html rendered